# Storing the result of blended images in AS3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I am making an interactive animation which background images are masked by a shape captured in a camera. In the every frames, camera changes images into black and white images and then it's used to mask background images.

In the code, "now" is the images captured by camera, "P1" is the back ground image.

After I masked by using blend mode multiply, I wish to store the result image which is masked and use for other things.
I don't understand when I use blendmode function, how the result is defined well.
Can I capture, copy or store the result image?

```
var P1:MovieClip = new p1();
var mskimg:MovieClip = new maskimage();

var bitmap_obj:Bitmap = new Bitmap(now);

addChild(P1);
P1.blendMode = BlendMode.LAYER;
addChild(bitmap_obj);
bitmap_obj.blendMode = BlendMode.MULTIPLY;
```

[image]

Comment: You can draw the parent with the BitmapData class,  this all very expensive though if your doing it every frame.

Comment: [Look at my example on the documentation site](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/actionscript-3/2814/drawing-bitmaps/9508/draw-a-display-object-into-bitmap-data#t=20160728215336898734)  - use that function and pass in the parent of the blended elements (looks to be `this` if in the context of your code)

Comment: This is the [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#draw()) on the draw method.

Comment: Define "store for other things"... You want to save a still jpeg (screen grab) as file on disk? Or you want it in memory for other code in your app to use? Also does "store the result image" mean really one image or you want to make video sequence (again specify if.. to save on disk or to keep in app's memory during usage only). The correct answer depends on these details.

Comment: To store an image or object to use in the code again. Not video nor saving as a file. I'm trying to do the things you all are writing now. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can draw a masked object if you put everything that you intend to be drawn into a container, then call `BitmapData.draw()` to draw the complete layered object to some `BitmapData`. Then, you can use that bitmap data to do whatever you want, `Graphics.beginBitmapFill()`, `FileReference.save()`, whatever. The operation is however expensive, so it'll be better if you trigger the drawing by responding to a user action, and not do that every frame by default, unless required by your application's logic.

Comment: Thank you very much! I could understand better about Bitmap and BitmapData now and could do what I was trying to do. Thank you also for mentioning about the cost of the function. I will be careful about that.